excel data formatting match up positive/negative from 2 columns
I need help or improve my current excel formula for matching positive and negative pairing.
My current excel formula is:

=AND(R4<>0,COUNTIF($R$4:$T$200,R4)+COUNTIF($R4:$T$200,R4*-1)>1)

This one seems not to accurately pair matching negative/positive. I have 2 columns R and T, i want to pair up all numbers under columns R and T, highlighting positive and negative match results

Heres the sample formula with data formatting rule image

As you see, some numbers in column "R" found a positive/negative pair in "T" but it doesnt highlight

In the second COUNTIF a $ sign is missing before the number 4.

What happens if there's a positive pairing, would you want to ignore those or still highlight? I'd imagine you'd want to use an ABS() formula. Otherwise the second formula $R4 should be $R$4

There is a systematic error that can catch you out with floating point numbers in Excel (and elsewhere). It doesn't apply it's rules entirely consistently so you can have numbers which look alike and normally compute to zero sum but are in fact very slightly different (enough to break a test for exact numerical equality).
The most likely one is that the numbers look alike but because of how they have been computed do not pass an exact equality test. To illustrate this rounding problem with floating point numbers try the following:
A1 : -234.3
B1 : = 200.1 + 30.1 + 4.1
C1 : = MATCH(A1,B$1:B$99,0)
D1 : = 1-A1/B1
E1 : = (1-A1/B1)

or paste this string into cell A1

-234.3,=200.1+30.1+4.1,"=MATCH(A1,B$1:B$99,0)",=1+A1/B1,=(1+A1/B1)

Cells A1 and B1 will both display 234.3 with opposite signs, C1 displays #N/A and a naieve computation of the difference in Excel in D1 will show "0". However, putting it in brackets forces full numerical precision evaluation and reveals the tiny rounding error of 2.22e-16 which breaks the equality test. Your practical options are to make the equality test slightly fuzzy and so accept e.g. ABS(1-A1/B1) < 8.88e-16 as OK.
It is a side effect of decimal value 0.1 having an infinite binary expansion and is reflected in the various threads "Is floating point math broken"
I'm not sure that colouring in the ones that do match up is all that much help unless you also provide the index down column T where the match was found. I think adding a new helper column containing the result of match -R4 onto  column T might be more useful for your spreadsheet (with the N/A's suppressed). You may be able to exploit a variant of the formula in d1 to find those that sum to zero in normal Excel usage. I think the following conditional might do what you want:
=MIN(1+ABS(R$4:T$400/R4))=0

And it is amenable to fuzzing by changing 0 to 9e-16 if required.
